# Document Preview Word, Excel and Powerpoint Support Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, document-library, file-icons, preview

I'm looking for a way to make a SharePoint library preview fully functional with all types of documents using Javascript. So far the preview feature only works with images and PDF's.

This is the script I am using for my library to load the preview by clicking the icon types of each document.

```
function hookupToExpGroup() {
 var defaultExpCollGroupMethod = ExpCollGroup; 
 ExpCollGroup = function() {  
 defaultExpCollGroupMethod.apply(this, arguments);
 setTimeout(searchATags,2000);
 };
}
function hookupToRefreshPageTo() {
 var defaultRefreshPageToMethod = RefreshPageTo; 
 RefreshPageTo = function() {  
 defaultRefreshPageToMethod.apply(this, arguments);
 setTimeout(searchATags,2000);
 };
}
function insertClick(oLink, oImg) {
 oLink.id = "my_anchor_" + i;
 oImg.id = "my_hover_" + i;
 oImg.onclick = function() {
  var res = this.id.split("_");
  var lastIndex = res.length - 1;
  var anchorId = "my_anchor_" + res[lastIndex];
  href = document.getElementById(anchorId).href;
  var options = { url: href, width: 800, height: 600 };
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 } 
}
function searchATags() {
 var aTagsTotal = document.links.length;
 for (i = 0; i
```

Like I said it fully works on images and PDF's but if I were to click on any other type document, it gets stuck on the "Working On it" Screen when previewing.

***Preview for images and pdf document types; works fine when icon is clicked***
[image: preview for images and pdf file types works fine when icon is clicked]
***Word, Excel and Powerpoint Document types don't work on preview***
[image: Word, Excel and Powerpoint Document file types don't work on preview]

Can Anyone explain or help, why is this happening and how I can adjust coding to make work or find the solution within SharePoint itself?

Answer (score -1):

You need Office Web App for the script to be capable with any javascript.